# Writing a .bat file to run a .py file in the Python interpreter

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, anaconda

In general, the problem is that I use Anaconda and, unlike IDLE, you can’t just associate .py files with the Python interpreter there, since many environments are used there and the necessary environment must be activated before running the .py file. You can't do without writing a .bat file. I've never done this and don't know the cmd syntax. I found how to activate the environment I need with a .bat file, but I can't open the file I need in it. I already agree to set it statically through a text editor, but ideally, of course, the path to it should be passed as an argument so that in the system settings I can put the association of .py files with the .bat file I need.

It should turn out something like:

```
@echo off
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Joanit\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Joanit\anaconda3\envs\Study
@cd /d d:/Download
@python 1.py
```

But this does not work, it does not go to the folder I need, but if I enter these commands sequentially manually through the console, the program starts and works fine.

Result of running .bat file:
[image: Result of running .bat file]

Sequential command entry:
[image: Sequential command entry]

Comment: Change line 2 to ```Call "%UserProfile%\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "%UserProfile%\anaconda3\envs\Study"```

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Bat_To_Exe_Converter program](https://bat-to-exe-converter-x64.en.softonic.com/download), which converts .bat files to .exe. It also allows you to hide the command line when starting a .py file, set an icon for the resulting .exe file. The program allows you to associate .py files with the resulting .exe file, thereby allowing you to run .py files in the desired Anacond environment with a double click. Converted .bat file code:

```
@call activate Study
@cd /d %~d1%~p1
@python %~n1%~x1
```

After converting the .bat file can be deleted.
[Bat_To_Exe_Converter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9dJR.png)