# Adding some libraries to python script breaks double click to run

Tags: python, windows, spyder

I am trying to run a python script by double clicking on it. It works fine as long as certain libraries are not included.

The following sample code works and displays a window as desired (yes, I do need all those libraries but I have removed the main code for readability):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Mar 30 14:11:24 2023

@author: st4
"""
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import numpy as np
#import pandas as pd
#from matplotlib.figure import Figure
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform
#from io import BytesIO
#import win32com as win32

from datetime import datetime
from fpdf import FPDF
import PyPDF2
import os.path
import openpyxl as xls
from datetime import date
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import sys
import ctypes

#----Some code here----

# alert that program is done
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, "Done!", u'Alert', 0)
```

If I uncomment any of the commented libraries then the console window opens and closes immediately, without doing anything else. I have tried reinstalling those libraries but nothing changes. I have tried suggestions from other answers here but they seem relevant about running script on click 'at all' whereas my setup works fine except if those libraries are included. The full code including all libraries runs fine in Spyder. This is on windows 10 btw. Does anybody know what I am missing?

Comment: open your command prompt `cmd.exe` and navigate to that folder, then run `python myscript.py` and paste what you get into the question, also make sure you deactivate any environment before you do, so if you have anaconda you have to type `conda deactivate`.

Comment: @AhmedAEK  It runs as long as conda is activated. otherwise it says: " 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Isn't this expected if I have anaconda?

Comment: then you have to activate the anaconda environment first, this is probably what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/74371867/15649230

Comment: @AhmedAEK the link doesn't help. you were right about activating anaconda first! Posting the solution in an edit. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix; Thank you @AhmedAEK !
So this is an issue caused by anaconda. You need to activate anaconda before the script. The workaround to run the script with a double click (or on startup) is to create a .bat file with the following code:

```
    call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat 
    cd C:\Users\{path to python script} 
    python {yourscript.py}
    pause
```

and use that .bat file to double click or put in the startup folder.